# How to search values from multiple tables using wildcards?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, wildcard

I'm doing wild card searching with JDBC.

The code is working fine when I use a single table.

When I try to combine multiple tables using a wild card search, the code doesn't work.

For example, the user may search  any keyword.

1. if the user searches for "*cricket*", the cricket keyword is availble in the sports table
2. if the user searches for "*windows 8*", it is available in the software table
3. if the user searches for "*google, yahoo*", the keywords are available in the website table

Here is the dynamic input value:

```
where s1(cricket,windows 8,google)
```

In the single table search I look for "*cricket*" in the sports table.

Here is my query, which works fine:

```
"select * from sports WHERE feed LIKE '%" +s1 + "%'";
```

My multiple table query does not work.

```
    "select * from  product  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%'" "OR 

    "select * from  sports     WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%'" " OR

    "select * from  website  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%'" " OR

    "select * from  software  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%'" "OR

    "select * from   other   WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%'"
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: In your single query you say where feed like and in your multitable where sitename like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concat your single statements with a `UNION` instead of a `OR`. With this you can concat several SQL-Queries and tables with the same columns. For Example:

```
"select * from  product  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%' UNION 

 select * from  sports   WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%' UNION

 select * from  website  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%' UNION

 select * from  software  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%' UNION

 select * from   other   WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%'" ;
```

But be aware! Your single tables must have the same columns/ columncount, otherwise it won't work!
Maybe better example to clarify:

```
"select sitename, description from  product  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%' UNION 

 select sitename, description from  sports   WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%' UNION

 select sitename, description from  website  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%' UNION

 select sitename, description from  software  WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%' UNION

 select sitename, text as description from   other   WHERE sitename LIKE '%"+s1+"%'" ;
```

As you can see in Statement 6, you can refer other columns to your result by renaming them, but the columncount has to be the same.

Hope this may help you!